# Why does the Symfony DkimSigner() not read my private key?

Tags: php, symfony

Hope you are keeping well !!

I keep getting a DkimSigner error. "Unable to load DKIM private key"

I have added various debugs to check that the private key is readable
and I created the key directly on the server with:
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out priv_key.pem

I assume I must have got something wrong even though my debugs are not showing it.

This is the full error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Mime\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Unable to load DKIM private key: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line in /home/aiaugdju/prod.aiauto.cloud/main2/app_main/vendor/symfony/mime/Crypto/DkimSigner.php:47

I'm running PHP 8.1

I am trying to move from SendinBlue to use Symfony

and this is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "kekek/devenilu",
    "description": "A simple deamon for collecting data from a central server, Csv",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "symfony/mailer": "^6.3",
        "ext-pdo": "*",
        "sendinblue/api-v3-sdk": "^8.4",
        "ezyang/htmlpurifier": "^4.14"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "",
            "App\\Core\\": "core",
            "tests\\": "tests"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use SendinBlue\Client\Api\ContactsApi;
use SendinBlue\Client\Api\TransactionalEmailsApi;
use SendinBlue\Client\Model\SendSmtpEmail;
use SendinBlue\Client\Model\SendSmtpEmailAttachment;
use SendinBlue\Client\Model\SendSmtpEmailAttachmentUrl;

use SendinBlue\Client\Configuration;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Mailer;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Crypto\DkimSigner;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;


class IMailer
{
    /**
     * @param $recipient
     * @param $subject
     * @param $html_body :
     * @param $attachment_path
     * @return void
     * @throws TransportExceptionInterface
     */
public static function  
     sendEmail($subject,$to_mail,$to_name,$htmlContent,$attachment,$newData)
    {
    
    ....  other code for attachments
    
    
        // DKIM private key path and selector
        $dkimPrivateKeyPath = 'priv_key.pem';
        $dkimSelector = 'nc-aiauto';
        $dkimDomain = 'aiauto.cloud';
        
        if (!file_exists($dkimPrivateKeyPath)) {
            die("DKIM private key file not found.");
            }

        // Setup the SMTP transport
        // The DSN format for SMTP connections should follow the pattern: 
      smtp://username:password@host:port.
        $transport = Transport::fromDsn("smtp://$smtpUsername:" . 
      urlencode($smtpPassword) . "@$smtpHost:$smtpPort");

        // Create the Mailer
        $mailer = new Mailer($transport);

        // Compose the email
        $email = (new Email())
            ->from($smtpUsername)
            ->to($to_mail)
            ->subject($subject)
            ->html($htmlContent);
            
        // Create a new Attachment instance
        
        if ($attachment !== 'N' ){
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                $email->attachFromPath($attachment['url'], $attachment['name']);
                }
            }
        try {
            // Sign the email with DKIM
            
            // Output the contents of the private.pem file
            $privateKeyContent = file_get_contents($dkimPrivateKeyPath);
            echo "Private Key Contents:\n";
            echo $privateKeyContent;
            
            $privateKey = 
     openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents($dkimPrivateKeyPath));
            if (!$privateKey) {
                die("Unable to load DKIM private key.");
            } else {
                echo "LOADED Private Key\n";
            }

            $signer = new DkimSigner($dkimPrivateKeyPath, $dkimDomain, $dkimSelector );
            $signedEmail = $signer->sign($email);

            // Send the email...
            $mailer->send($signedEmail);
            file_put_contents("processError.log", 'SendEmail-02  SENT EMAIL To: ' 
         .$to_mail. "\n", FILE_APPEND);  // FLAG SendEmail-02
            return true;
        } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
            // Handle transport exceptions...
            $errorMessage = "SendEmail-03 Error sending email: " . $e->getMessage();
            file_put_contents("processError.log", $errorMessage . "\n", FILE_APPEND);         
          // FLAG SendEmail-03
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The debug output is :

```
./cron.sh
Private Key Contents:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
LOADED Private Key

Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Mime\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Unable to load DKIM private key: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line in /ho
```

me/aiaugdju/prod.aiauto.cloud/main2/app_main/vendor/symfony/mime/Crypto/DkimSigner.php:47

So, it seems that openssl_pkey_get_private() can read the private key file but DkimSigner() can not.

As you can see, I moved the private key right into the work directory
in order to make the path easy ( of course, normally it would be elsewhere )

Please let me know what I can do to get this working.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried specifying full path to file instead of relative? `$dkimPrivateKeyPath = __DIR__ . '/priv_key.pem';`? Because it is being read from different locations (DkimSigner is in different path than your script, but still tries to read as key is in same dir)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried this: $signer = new DkimSigner('priv_key.pem', 'aiauto.cloud', 'nc-aiauto' );  still get same error.

Comment: `priv_key.pem` is still relative path. Provide full path from root

Comment: You have to prefix the value with `file://` (see [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php)). So you would pass `file://priv_key.pem` then (but it should be the absolute path, as [@Justinas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346234) wrote). Without the prefix, it will be interpreted as the key itself, not a file.